# Why the toolbar button icon is grey at runtime?

Tags: .net, icons, infragistics

I"m setting the icon of a toolbar button (using Infragistics component library for the toolbar), The problem is that on design time the icon is showing normally. But at runtime the icon become greyed, though the drawing of the icon is still apparent, but its colors are all lost and the shape of the icon image is grey. So i'm wondering if it's colour related bug, or I need to tweek something in VS, or it is a bug in the library i'm using i.e. Infragistics.

So anyone faced that problem before and fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I am now aware of this Infragistics, but check if the icon has some property like Enabled os isEnable

Answer (score 0):

For the classis toolbar appareance, is the "RenderMode" responsable fo the toolbar "look" - it can be system, professional, etc.